# How is this a type mismatch?

Tags: scala, types

```
  val eventListeners = new HashMap[Class[Event], ArrayBuffer[Event => Unit]]

  def addEventListener[A <: Event](f: A => Unit)(implicit mf: ClassManifest[A]): A => Unit = {
    eventListeners.getOrElseUpdate(mf.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[Event]], ArrayBuffer[Event => Unit]()) += f
    f
  }
```

Is throwing:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (A) => Unit
 required: (this.Event) => Unit
    eventListeners.getOrElseUpdate(mf.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[Event]], ArrayBuffer[Event => Unit]()) += f
```

Why is it saying that it found `(A) => Unit`? The value of `f` is a function that is `(Event) => Unit`. Isn't `A` just a type parameter, not the signature?

Example call:
`addEventListener { e:FooEvent => .... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `Function1` is contra-variant on its parameter. Ie, its type is `Function1[-T, +R]`.

That means a function of `Any => Unit` is a subtype of `Event => Unit`, but for `A` a subtype of `Event`, `A => Unit` is a _super_type of `Event => Unit`.

Ergo, the problem. If you change the type parameter to `A >: Event`, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You are promising your `ArrayBuffer` that you will give it a function that can take any `Event` and turn it into a `Unit` (presumably doing something interesting along the way).

But you are giving it a function that can only take `A`s, which may not encompass all `Event`s.  That is clearly not what you've promised, so the compiler complains.

You need to figure out what ought to happen in that case, and write code accordingly.  For example, you could create a new function `g` that does nothing in case it receives an `Event` that, according to your class manifest, is not an `A`, and otherwise applies `f`.  Or you could require all listeners to take events of all sorts, and be responsible themselves for throwing away the events that they don't want to bother with.

---

Edit: just to make things clearer with an example,

```
abstract class Fruit { def tasty: String }

class Banana extends Fruit { def tasty = "Yum!" }

abstract class SeededFruit extends Fruit {
  def seedCount: Int
  def tasty = "Mmm, mmm."
}

class Peach extends SeededFruit { def seedCount = 1 }
class Apple extends SeededFruit { def seedCount = 5 }

val tellAboutSeeds = (sf: SeededFruit) => println("There are "+sf.seedCount+"seeds")

val fruitTeller = new collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Fruit=>Unit]
fruitTeller += tellAboutSeeds  // If this worked...
fruitTeller(0)(new Banana)     // ...we'd be in trouble!
```

Comment: Doesn't `A <: Event` make it so `A` *does* encompass all `Event`s?

Comment: @ryeguy `A <: Event` means that `A` is a specialization/subtype of `Event`.

Comment: @ziggystar: Right, so if `A` is a subtype of `Event`, why doesn't `A => Unit` mean the same as `Event => Unit`?

Comment: @ryeguy Only because you can drive a *car* does not mean you can drive any *vehicle* (or even *anything*, as a *car* is also a specialization of *anything*).

Comment: @ziggystar clever example. I like it!